# How to mute and unmute sound using sound manager 2?

Tags: javascript, audio, soundmanager2

I am using sound manager 2 for giving sound to my site.. Now i want mute and unmute sound on

clicking a button. I tried `mute()` and `unmute()` functions. But didnt get the result.

My code for mute is :

```
function mutesound(){
            soundManager.mute(); // mute all sounds

            soundManager.createSound({
             id: 'msound',
             url: 'folder/sound/click.mp3',
             autoLoad:true,
             onload: function() {
               soundManager.mute('msound'); 

              } 
            });
        }
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: show some code. What sound is not muting?

Answer (score 0):

mute() and unmute() are *[methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/what-is-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)*, you should apply these to the SoundManager object. Which is by default called `soundManager`.

```
soundManager.toggleMute()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a variable so you can call it afterwards I think. Something like

```
var player = soundManager.createSound({ 
  ...
});

player.mute();

player.unmute();
```

Tell me what happens.